# AngularJS on a Load balance

Tags: angularjs, load-balancing

- I have a web application developed by AngularJS and deployed to Tomcat on a load balance with two instances.
- When I make any change that requires database update, I'm able to find this change while some of my colleagues are not able to see the same change.
- When I checked the direct URLs, I found the change on only one instance of the two instances.
- It seems that only the Load balance Instance that I'm pointing to when I do the change got updated from the database while the other Instance doesn't.
- How can I solve this issue? Could you please Advise?

Regards,
Eman Azmy

Comment: Has nothing to do with AngularJS. This is a Tomcat question and you should provide your tomcat-loadbalancing settings. Of course you should use only one database, not two.

Comment: Sure, I use only one Database. It's not a Tomcat issue because I didn't  face the same problem on the other applications deployed to the same Tomcat with load balance and using different technologies